# 右辺値参照宣言子&&にユースケースはありますか？

Tags: c++, c++11

私はC++について勉強中ですが、以下のようなコードに対するメリットが発見できませんでした。

```cpp
Obj a;
Obj&& b = std::move(a);
```

aをrvalueとみなして、再利用しないという意味づけを行うにもかかわらず、bで参照できるようにするメリットはどこにありますか？

また、仮引数に対して用いる場合も、templateとの併用をしない場合のユースケースはありますか？
Argument deductionを用いたtemplateと併用する場合：

```cpp
template<typename T>
void swap(T &&a, T &&b){
    auto tmp = std::forward<T>(a);
    a = std::forward<T>(b);
    b = std::forward<T>(tmp);
}

//　単にmoveするだけなら以下でよいのではないでしょうか

template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b){
    auto tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

右辺値参照を受け取る場合を明示したオーバーロードの場合では有効に使えそうです。
以下Objの実装でのムーブコンストラクタなど：

```cpp
class Obj{
public:
    int *data; 
    Obj(){
        Init();
    };
    ~Obj(){
        UnInit();
    }
    Obj(const Obj& other){
        Init();
        *this = other;
    };
    Obj(Obj&& other){
        Init();
        *this = std::move(other);
    };
    Obj& operator=(const Obj& other){
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
        std::copy(other.data, other.data + SIZE, data);
        return *this;
    }
    Obj& operator=(Obj&& other){
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
        data = other.data;
        other.data = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    void Init(){
        data = new int(SIZE);
        std::cout << "construct" << std::endl;
    }
    void UnInit(){
        delete[] data;
        std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

この他にユースケースはありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Obj a;
> Obj&& b = std::move(a);
> ```
>
> aをrvalueとみなして、再利用しないという意味づけを行うにもかかわらず、bで参照できるようにするメリットはどこにありますか？

上記コードが有用なケースは無いと思います。変数`b`は右辺値参照型`Obj&&`ではありますが、実際にムーブ操作を行うときは改めて右辺値へのキャスト`std::move(b)`が必要になります。

```
Obj a;
Obj&& b = std::move(a);
Obj c = std::move(b);  // 変数cへムーブ
// Obj c = b; では単にコピーが行われる
```

---

> 仮引数に対して用いる場合も、templateとの併用をしない場合のユースケースはありますか？

いまひとつ質問意図を読み取れなかったのですが、C++標準ライブラリ提供の[関数テンプレート`std::swap`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/utility/swap.html)では右辺値参照型`T&&`を用いません。

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b);
// (constexprやnoexceptは省略)
```

---

> 右辺値参照を受け取る場合を明示したオーバーロードの場合では有効に使えそうです。

基本的には、まさに例示のようなクラス実装で利用されるものですね。

> この他にユースケースはありますか？

かなりのレアケースですが、[`std::ref`関数テンプレート](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/functional/ref.html)では「右辺値を誤って受け取らない」ように、右辺値参照型`const T&&`が利用されています。

```
// std::ref関数テンプレートのオーバーロード(一部)
template <class T>
reference_wrapper<T> ref(T& t);

template <class T>
void ref(const T&&) = delete;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。意図不明瞭、申し訳ありません。swapは例として良くないものでした。templateによって、実引数が右辺値か左辺値かによって処理を分岐させることを意図したものです。(例えば、無意味な例ですが、`void copy(T&&a,T&&b){a = std::forward<T>(b);}`などとすれば、`copy(obj0,obj1);`と`copy(std::move(obj0), std::move(obj1));`でコピーかムーブかを変えられるといった例）

Comment: 「templateとの併用をしない」＝通常(メンバ)関数の仮引数として`U&`と`U&&`を使い分けるユースケースというニュアンスでしょうか？少しでも[ムーブ／コピー回数を削減したい](https://yohhoy.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20120524/p1)場合には、`const U&`と`U&&`で関数オーバーロードを提供することがあり得ます。